# Biztalk 2013r2 wcf-sql adapter composite operation

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2013r2

I am trying to use the wcf-sql adapter to call a stored procedure multiple times with different parameters. I have created the original schema using the wizard and then created the composite schema by hand. I understand what the error is telling me I just do not understand why I am getting the error and/or how to resolve it.

> Error: Microsoft.ServiceModel.Channels.Common.MetadataException:
>   Object [dbo].[DEPT_NUM] of type StoredProcedure does not exist. The
>   message that is suspended in Biztalk looks like this...

```
<ns0:DINV_sumDepartmentInventory xmlns:ns0="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Sql/2008/05/TypedProcedures/dbo"><ns0:DEPT_NUM> 4</ns0:DEPT_NUM><ns0:INV_DATE>2016-03-21T00:00:00</ns0:INV_DATE><ns0:USERNAME>Service</ns0:USERNAME></ns0:DINV_sumDepartmentInventory>
```

This is the portion of the orchestration...

[image: Ochestration]

This is the map that is associated with the "transform_3" shape...

[image]

This is what the composite schema looks like...

[image]

I am expecting the output to more like this...

```
<ns1:Request xmlns:ns1="http://BigY.PICSInventory.Updated_SQL_Schemas.Composite_SumDepartmentInventory" xmlns:ns0="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Sql/2008/05/TypedProcedures/dbo"><ns0:DINV_sumDepartmentInventory><ns0:DEPT_NUM>4</ns0:DEPT_NUM><ns0:INV_DATE>2016-03-21T00:00:00</ns0:INV_DATE><ns0:USERNAME>Service</ns0:USERNAME></ns0:DINV_sumDepartmentInventory></ns1:Request>
```

Any ideas what is wrong with the setup or what else I can try?

Comment: Can you show us what the send port looks like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the Composite Operation is not composed correctly.  It has to be a very specific structure with certain namespaces and Operation.

This Wiki Article explains the process step by step: [BizTalk Server: Streamlining WCF SQL and Oracle Messaging-Only and Other Patterns](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/26279.biztalk-server-streamlining-wcf-sql-and-oracle-messaging-only-and-other-patterns.aspx)

Comment: Update: Issue was caused by a mismatch in the namespaces between the composite schema and the imported schema(s)